# Match entries in sales: How can i add a custom field to the article title?

Tags: expresso-store

In a wine shop article titles are very often identical. That makes it difficult for my client to choose the right product to be on a sales list. This screenshot should say it all:

[image]

Is it possible to change that? Something like this would be perfect in my case:

custom_field-title (the custom field is the wine ID in my clients workflow, for example 1234. That's not the ExpressionEngine entry_id. That would show something like this:

1234-Chardonnay

If custom_field-title is not possible: article_id-title would be already some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try [MX Title Control](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-title-control) (free) - you can create any title or url  template using any ee tags.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the various addons which automatically generate a descriptive title?

E.g. http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/title-master

That way you can use your own custom field as the actual title, and leave the entry title for something more descriptive in relationship fieldtypes etc.

Comment: OK, it works now with the MX Title Control. Unfortunately custom fields are not accessible in the {exp:store:checkout} tag. (or am i understanding something wrong?) I have to use the "CE String" plugin to strstr the ID to list the proper article name in the cart. Or is there another way?

Comment: You can just put an `{exp:channel:entries}` tag inside the `{items}` loop to access custom fields - see https://exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#entry_id

Comment: Thats much better than strstr ... I totally missed that one. Thanks!